# JavaScript Charting with non-uniform data, displayed with uniform axes labels, without upsampling data source

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm looking for a Javascript charting framework that allows for non-uniform x-axis spacing. I have perused *many* JS charting frameworks, but the online documentation that I have found universally does not make clear whether or not the tool allows irregularly-spaced x-axis values.

I know that one solution is to just resample my data at the GCD of my data points, but that is impractical given the size of my dataset. Instead, it would be most beneficial if I could simply plot only the x-axis values I choose.

Is there any tool that contains this capability?

Edit: It's fine if the chart has a uniform axis, but I want my data source to be non-uniform. In other words, it's ok if my axis goes `1 2 3 4 5 6 7`, but I might only want to plot data at `2 3 5 7`.

Edit 2: What I really want is a JS library that can make a plot look like this:

[image]

which is easily generated by the following MATLAB code:

```
t = [ 13.23, 105.81, 196.40]; y = [ 10, 11.5, 14.8]; plot(t,y);
hold on
plot(t,y,'o','MarkerSize',6)
axis([0 200 0 20])
```

Comment: That last edit really has me confused. Almost any charting library can create an X-Y graph in which data doesn't exist at uniform x-axis values. Can you show an example data set and possibly a simple sketch of what you want? As for a non-uniform x-axis (although that seems dangerous in terms of best practices), a low-level library such as D3 lets you create any axis you want. In particular, you'd need to create a custom scale.

Comment: @stephenthomas a uniform scale is fine, but my data are not at uniform points. Suppose I wanted to plot the times at which I take my dog out to do business, and his long each visit takes. A standard 24 hour linear axis is acceptable, but I oy want to plot an event, say, at 9 AM, 12:41 PM, 5:16 PM, and 10:11 PM without turning my x-axis data source into a 1440-element array.

Comment: Every charting library that I've used does exactly as you want.

Comment: @StephenThomas Whilst still keeping uniform axis labels? If so, perhaps you could suggest me your favorite?

Comment: I'd suggest starting [here](http://jsdatav.is/intro.html)

Comment: It seems like null values are what you're looking for -  [null, data, data, null, data, null, data] where "data" is a value at 2, 3, 5, and 7. As Stephen mentioned, any charting library should be able to do that.

Comment: @Chlorination That's not really a viable solution, though, when I want to plot time series data. Suppose I need to plot data as in my comment -- I would have 5 data events, and 1395 null events. Now let's scale that further; suppose I want to plot event log data, rounded to deciseconds. I can't take a 20-minute window and up-sample it to deciseconds, and have 99% of the vector be null.

Comment: What I'd really like is to supply my data as follows: `time : [ 13.23, 105.81, 196.40]; data : [ 10, 11.5, 14.8]; xticks : [0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200]`

Comment: See my latest edits.

Comment: Your matlab code can be trivially ported to any JavaScript charting library. Per Stack Overflow guidelines, show us what you've tried and what errors you've encountered. Otherwise, this question should be closed as inappropriate.

Comment: @StephenThomas I've tried looking at the documentation for several charting libraries, but all charting libraries that I've tried link the axes labels to the data source. I don't know of any that don't.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, what the heck. Using, for example, [Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org):

```
$.plot("#placeholder", [ 
    [[13.23, 10], [105.81, 11.5], [196.40, 14.8]]
],{
    xaxis: { min: 0, max: 200 },
    yaxis: { min: 0, max: 20  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In [ZingChart](http://www.zingchart.com), you can use [x,y] pairs in the values array.

```
   "scale-x":{
       "values":"0:200:20"
   },
   "scale-y":{
       "values":"0:20:2" 
   },
   "series": [
       {
           "values": [[13.23,10],[105.81,11.5],[196.40,14.8]]
       }
    ]
```

Here's a [live demo](http://demos.zingchart.com/view/6NSTZP4T).

Disclaimer: I'm on the ZingChart team. If you have any questions about implementation, feel free to give us a holler.